# urllib.URLopener().retrieve give me http error 403

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using `python manage.py` shell. When i send the following code:

```python
import requests
import json
import urllib
import gzip
import csv
from usuario.models import Usuario
from calculadora.models import Prazo
r = requests.post("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/csv_export?app_id=*****", headers={"Authorization": "Basic *****"})
url = json.loads(r.content)["csv_file_url"]
file = urllib.URLopener()
file.retrieve(url, "C:\Users\legal\Desktop\file.gz")
f = gzip.open("C:\\Users\\legal\\Desktop\\file.gz")
arquivo = csv.reader(f)
```

The following error appears:

```
IOError: ('http error', 403, 'Forbidden', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x05551990>)
```

But, if I send first :

```
import requests
import json
import urllib
import gzip
import csv
from usuario.models import Usuario
from calculadora.models import Prazo
r = requests.post("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/csv_export?app_id=*****", headers={"Authorization": "Basic ******"})
url = json.loads(r.content)["csv_file_url"] 
file = urllib.URLopener()
```

and then:

```
file.retrieve(url, "C:\Users\legal\Desktop\file.gz")
f = gzip.open("C:\\Users\\legal\\Desktop\\file.gz")
arquivo = csv.reader(f)
```

The code run without any error, and I can't understand what's happening.

Comment: Check to see if your authorization  key is correct. 403 usually means the server aceepts you are giving a request, but refuses to respond

Comment: yes, it's correct, i already checked. The code runs if i send part by part, but if i send it at once, doesn't work. I need to slip the code on" file = urlib.URLopener()" for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was sync, i solve this using:

`f = urllib.URLopener()
time.sleep(5)
f.retrieve(url, "C:\Users\\legal\\Desktop\\file.gz")`